# Importing or bypassing a complicated SDK

Tags: sdk, geospatial, point-cloud-library, geo, point-clouds

I'm writing a program (C#) to read, convert, display, adjust and output point cloud data.

I can make every part of the program except for one - I am required to read in a proprietary file format.  The data is coming straight from a laser scanner and we cannot get any closer to the stream than what is output to the proprietary file in binary.

I have an SDK from the manufacturer/proprietor that is well outside my scope of ability to deal with.

Firstly it is written in C++, which I can read and write to some degree but this all appears incredibly complex (there are hundred of header/source files).
Secondly, the SDK documentation says that I must create my SLN using CMake which is a nightmare for me also.
Thirdly, the documentation is scarce and horrid.

Basically my question is this:

I know that after a certain amount of header information I should find thousands of lines of "lineref,x,y,z,r,g,b,time,intensity".
Can I bypass the SDK and find another way to read in this file type?
Or, must an SDK from the proprietor be used to interact with their file type due to some sort of encryption?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: If the manufacturer took 100's of files to implement the sdk, it is probably complex, and it is unlikely you want to re-implement it.